# List items disappear into thin air

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a few lists of items, one called "currentInputs" which is what the user is meant to be able to add to by pressing keys, and "keyInputs" which is the list of authorized keys that the user can enter. The issue is that whenever I enter a key into "currentInputs" then the same key disappears from "keyInputs" meaning that each key can only be pressed once, ever. I'm not sure what is causing this, please help.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class inputManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public keyboardManager toCall;
    public List<KeyInput> _keyInputs;
    public List<KeyInput> _currentInputs;


    void Start()
    {
        _currentInputs = new List<KeyInput>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        GetKeyInputs();
        toCall.GetInputs(_currentInputs);
    }

    private void GetKeyInputs()                         //finds all keyboard inputs on this frame
    {
        foreach (KeyInput input in _keyInputs)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(input.key))
            {
                _currentInputs.Add(input);
            }

            if (Input.GetKeyUp(input.key))
            {
                _currentInputs.Remove(input);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

All other code is here

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class keyboardManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<KeyInput> useableInputs;
    public List<GameObject> physicalKeys;


    public List<KeyInput> activeKeys;
    public List<KeyInput> lastActiveKeys;              //active means this key is down, inactive means this key is up, and dead means this key was recently released and is now recharging
    public List<KeyInput> inactiveKeys;
    public List<KeyInput> deadKeys;
    private List<KeyInput> releasedKeys;
    public List<KeyInput> temp;

    public inputManager inp;

    void Start()
    {
        useableInputs = new List<KeyInput>();
        lastActiveKeys = new List<KeyInput>();
        inactiveKeys = inp._keyInputs;
    }


    public void GetInputs(List<KeyInput> newInputs)     //selects the correct inputs to use, first to execute
    {
        lastActiveKeys = activeKeys;
        releasedKeys = new List<KeyInput>();
        activeKeys = new List<KeyInput>();
        while (newInputs.Count > 0 && activeKeys.Count < 3)
        {
            temp = newInputs;

            if (deadKeys.Contains(newInputs[0]))
            {
                newInputs.RemoveAt(0);
            }
            else
            {
                inactiveKeys.Remove(newInputs[0]);
                activeKeys.Add(newInputs[0]);
                newInputs.RemoveAt(0);
            }
        }
        activeInactiveDead();
    }

    private void activeInactiveDead()                   //checks what is active or inactive or dead, second to execute
    {
        foreach (KeyInput k in lastActiveKeys)
        {
            if (!activeKeys.Contains(k))                //kills keys
            {
                releasedKeys.Add(k);
                deadKeys.Add(k);
                SpriteRenderer sprite = getGObject(k).GetComponent(typeof(SpriteRenderer)) as SpriteRenderer;
                sprite.color = Color.grey;
            }
        }
        foreach(KeyInput k in deadKeys)
        {
            SpriteRenderer sprite = getGObject(k).GetComponent(typeof(SpriteRenderer)) as SpriteRenderer;
            if(sprite.color == Color.white)
            {
                deadKeys.Remove(k);
                inactiveKeys.Add(k);                    //after .5 seconds, the key has returned to white and can be re used
            }
            else
            {
                sprite.color = Color.Lerp(Color.grey, Color.white, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, 1));
            }
        }
    }


    private GameObject getGObject(KeyInput k)
    {
        foreach(GameObject p in physicalKeys)
        {
            if(p.name == k.name)
            {
                print("found");
                return p;
            }
        }
        Debug.LogError("error object not found");
        return new GameObject();
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class KeyInput
{
        public string name;
        public KeyCode key;
}
```

Comment: What is `toCall.GetInputs(_currentInputs);` doing? Kindly please post, seems like the issue resides at that location.

Comment: I've edited the post to add the rest of my code, I couldn't find issues in it that would cause this bug, but maybe somebody else can

Comment: That is calling the function in the KeyboardManager part of the code, which then actually does something with the inputs it was given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you assign

```
inactiveKeys = inp._keyInputs;
```

so from now on both fields hold the exact same reference to the exact same list object. So every change in the `inactiveKeys` also applies to the same referenced list object `_keyInputs`.

Later you do

```
inactiveKeys.Remove(newInputs[0]);
```

where you remove that item from your list.

---

It seems that you actually just want a **COPY** of the list so you could use e.g.

```
inactiveKeys = new List<KeyInput>(inp._keyInputs);
```

Comment: damn I thought that it did just make a copy :/, thanks for the help!